# pyenvを使ってpythonをインストールしようとしているのですが。。。

Tags: python

[pyenvを使ってMacにPythonの環境を構築する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/1000ch/items/93841f76ea52551b6a97)

このサイトに従ってpyenvを使ってpythonをインストールしようとしているのですがうまくいきません。
OSはmacの10.10.1です。
上記のサイトで言う所のpyenvにパスを通す、というところまではできたのですが、
その次のpyenvでpythonをインストールすることができません。

SSL/TLSが必要と出てきたのでぐぐってみたのですがいまいちよくわかりません。

どうすれば先に進めるでしょうか
よろしくお願いします。

[image: ターミナルの操作中にエラーが出た部分です。]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このあたりが参考になりそう。きっと良くなります。

[pyenv のインストールメモ #python #mavericks - jitsu102's blog](http://jitsu102.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/01/212519)